# How do I add "padding" to features when applying d.out.file to map display on GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis

Thing is this. I've done up a script to automate some spatial interpolation and eventually output the interpolated raster and contour lines as an image of the map display. I'm doing this using `d.out.file`.

The issue now is, the features (mainly an island + the contours) are rendered right to the edge of the output image. I've tried using `d.zoom` to zoom out prior to the `d.out.file` command but to no avail.

Does any GRASS expert here know how I can place a "padding" so that my features don't end up right on the edge of the image? Post-processing won't cut it either as there are grids too. Also, it has to be done programmatically and not via the GUI.

**edit:** one more thing, I've got a raster mask in place so I'm not sure if that is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

My bad. I overlooked the fact that `g.region` was set as the raster mask extents. After adjusting to an custom set of North, South, East and West values, it works.